# is there a non AI way of classifying images into two groups in Python?

Tags: python, image-classification

I'm in the process of developing a parking app and need a way of classifying images of parking signs in the UK into their two colour types, yellow and white.

I've tried a number of methods in openCv and the reliability that I've found just isn't robust enough.

[White parking Sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY9UL.png)

[Yellow parking sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naZ15.jpg)

Alternatively, is there a quick/lightweight way of training an AI to classify these quickly,

thanks guys

Comment: Well, that lacks a bit of details...
Do you need to classify images with signs into it, or just signs images like the one you linked ? In the case you only want to classify sign images, why not browsing every pixel of the image, and getting the most-used colour (which sould be the fount, so either yellow or white) ?

Comment: Question: What do you mean when you say "AI"?

Comment: The problem is that the pictures will contain backgrounds, e.g: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alamy.com%2Fstock-photo-british-traffic-sign-no-stopping-parking-mon-sat-8am-630pm-56181176.html&psig=AOvVaw3ZPsTqHxhl8_Zg3fh4U3Dw&ust=1596699225186000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPi7_qLGg-sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABBh

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a simple classifier with 2 classes, but idk if it's what you call "ai". You might find some models fitting well on such problem (image classification) since it looks pretty easy on paper

Comment: @BeamsAdept thank you, I will look into this

Comment: I mean a machine learning model in which I would need to feed it training data of the two different sets of signs